# Ensure Timer fires after a given time span in C#

Tags: c#, timer

There are many questions about C# `System.Threading.Timer` on SO, but I cannot find this exact question.

In our code, we need to ensure that a timer fires **after**, and I mean after, a given amount of time.  If the timer fires .00001 seconds early, then that's bad.  On the other hand, if the timer fires even a few seconds late, that's OK.

I made [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8xnXbU) to show that the timer *sometimes* fires early.  Run it a few times and you'll see it (or increase `numSamples` in the code).  On my local PC, I've checked other time spans and they behave similarly, but dotnetfiddle doesn't allow your code to execute too long so `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` is what's in that demo.

One hack-ish way I've thought is to just sleep for a tenth of a second and that seems to catch the fuzzy-ness around `Timer`'s inaccuracy.  **Is there a canonical way to make sure that a time actually fires *after* a given time?**  I know there are [more accurate timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) in C#, but since our requirements allow for some wiggle room after the due time I figured there might be something cheaper that I've overlooked.

Thanks to @PaulF and @AlexeiLevenkov for your comments.  I think I fell victim to the XY problem.  My main concern was that the underlying "ground truth" for the time in the code I'm working in is `DateTime`'s time.  Trying to have an accurate timer with respect to an inaccurate "ground truth" is flawed.  I gave the answer I came up with below, and will accept it in the future.

Comment: You should not be relying on DateTime for that degree of accuracy. Note that you are printing time values with a far greater precision than the accuracy of DateTime & despite apparently firing too early they may be firing at the correct time. See this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/

Comment: If you know when next event should happen why not to compute interval every time? Notes - timers already fire after specified amount of time... As PaulF noted using 2 different sources/precision of time is likely another source of problems discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432160/c-sharp-timer-getting-fired-before-their-interval-time?rq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `Timer` handler, I put a piece of code in there like below.  This is not what I wanted to do, but considering that `DateTime` is what I need to make sure that I'm after in the body of the handler this is the best I can come up with.

```
private static void handler()
{
    // because I can handle a few second delay,
    // a delay of 1 second is acceptible to me
    while(DateTime.Now > _waitForThisDateTime) Thread.Sleep(1000);

    //Handler body here
}
```

Comments from @PaulF and @AlexeiLevenkov note that trying to have an accurate time with respect to the inaccurate `DateTime` is flawed, so I don't think there is a better answer.  The "fix" in the long term will be for me to change the existing code altogether to not have this requirement of being after a given `DateTime`!

As an aside, `Timer` seems to get less accurate the longer the `TimeSpan` that is passed to it.  Our time span is on the order of 1 day, so the errors I'm seeing are larger than in the demo I give in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

in your timer ElaptseHandler use thread.Sleep(100) or any amount you think fit to delay the actuall excution of your code

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
          timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();
          timer.Start();

 private static Task HandleTimer()
   {
     Thread.Sleep(100);
      //YOUR CODE HERE
   }
```

Comment: Note: Thread.Sleep should only be used if you are actually in a worker thread; using it on the main thread will freeze the program for the duration of the sleep, which is probably not what OP wants!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use quarzt.net [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) I have used and it's very easy to implement with nugget.

```
 // construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
  .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
  .StartNow()
  .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
      .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
      .RepeatForever())
  .Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

taken from website `http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/using-quartz.html`